# BitMap: создать анимированную модель

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, pascal

Здравствуйте, пришел к Вам с теоретическим вопросом, хочу в делфи создать анимированную модель, на ум приходит: сделать N картинок, массив из N элементов (кадров) каждый загружать и потом таймером прокручивать, но я знаю что профессионалы и вообще знающие люди, на каждую модель анимируют с помощью одной картинки. (Т.е. загружают одну, а там по координатам ее меняют). Но я не знаю как это реализовать, можете накинуть советиков?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать так, как Вы описываете, только используйте TBitmap для сохранения картинок и рисуйте в событии onPaint (таймер просто говорит компоненту, к примеру PaintBox, refresh, а компонент сам в своем событии рисует).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сказал особой разницы нет в одном файле у тебя все кадры или в разных. Если Вы спрашиваете, когда в одном файле нарисованы сразу все кадры и как отображать нужную область из этой картинки, то это делается с помощью OpenGL/DirectX библиотек. Тут все просто в шейдер посылаем текстуру, 4 текстурных координаты и 4 координаты позиции. И рисуем два треугольника. Кусочек кода:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glVertexAttribPointer(VertexAttrib_Position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertex));
glVertexAttribPointer(VertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, coords);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```